# How to make IntelliJ understand the Next.js `public` directory structure?

Tags: intellij-idea, next.js

I am using IntelliJ to edit a Next.js website.

- IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1
- Next.js 9.5.3-canary.23

Next.js [static file serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) uses a `/public` directory as a container for static assets, but when publishing a Next.js site, the contents of the `public` directory are hosted at the root of the site.

So, as shown in the linked doco, an image that exists in the codebase at `/public/my-image.png` is addressed by an URL path of `src="/my-image.png"`.

This confuses IntelliJ and it shows a warning that it can't resolve the directory of the `img` src:
[image]

I tried marking the `/public` directory as a "Source root" or a "Resources root" - but that didn't make the warning go away.
I also tried adding the `/public` directory as a "Content root", but IntelliJ doesn't want to do that because it overlaps with the root directory of the module, which is already a content root.

Is there any way to tell idea to look in the `/public` directory for statically referenced assets like this?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207019345-How-do-I-get-path-auto-completion-to-enter-paths-relative-to-my-public-folder-

Comment: @felixmosh I just tried everything in that thread with no luck.

Comment: [These docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html) seem related but also didn't help me solve the issue.

Comment: @NathanArthur Yeh, none of that stuff worked for me either.  I ended up declaring all my image sources as strings in a data structure.  IDEA still doesn't know about them, but they're all in one place, only ever defined once and can be re-used in multiple places. But best of all, the paths can be statically checked at build time - so your local build or even CI environment can tell you if you messed anything up.

Answer (score 17):

I've had the same problem. In my case, "Mark Directory as > Resource Root" worked well.

Before...

[image: Before]

Right click `./public`. Then Mark Directory as > Resource Root

[image: Mark Directory as > Resource Root]

After...

[image: After]

Image loads.

Comment: Oh man, this was driving me nuts. Fixed right away with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: image in markdown file not resolved